# Rstudio Latex download window

Tags: r, latex, rstudio

I recently downloaded Rstudio to one machine.  When knitting a sample markdown code, a window appeared asking to install a Latex package appeared. This window had a check box that says something about asking to download Latex packages and it the box was checked.  I unchecked it and I need to check it back again so I see which Latex packages I need to download. What are the steps to have this box checked again?

Comment: Are you using Rmarkdown or latex?  With the latex, if I \usepackage{} a package that I have not previously used, a box appears that asks whether I want to install the new package.  I do not know what happens with Rmarkdown.

Comment: In Rstudio you can create HTML, PDF, or Word documents when you knit a file.  When I do the PDF format, that's when the window was opening before I unchecked the box. This occurs when you first knit a PDF file.